# How minimize this PHP CODE

Tags: codeigniter-3

Anyone can help. I want to minimize my dirty code, I'm weak in logic. Thank you in advance..

```
//These are all fields
$prodname = $this->input->post('prodname');
$price = $this->input->post('price');
$qty = $this->input->post('qty');
$desc = $this->input->post('desc');
$status= $this->input->post('status');


// This part I want to minimize, or any shorthand for this code??
if ($prodname != NULL && $price != NULL && $qty != NULL && $desc != NULL && $status != NULL)
    $datas = $this->controller->add_product($data);
```

Comment: post your question in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: IF this is coming from a FORM. Then Yep, use codeigniters form_validation and you'll achieve that plus add some  validation to ensure the provided data from the form is what you are after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do the following:

```
//These are the fields coming from form "username" is the name of field

$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf', 'Password Confirmation', 'required');
```

Add as many rules you want to add and then you just want to confirm if it's validated or not, use this:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
   $this->load->view('myform');
}
else
{
   $this->load->view('formsuccess');
}
```

reference: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html